How to use angular flex-layout in angular 18
I have a large application built in Angular 17 that I've recently updated to Angular 18. Since the flex-layout packages do not officially support Angular 18, What can I do instead of overriding them to make npm install work.
Also in code, am using it like this:
 <div class="wrapper" fxFlex="grow" fxLayout="row">
    <fl-sidebar></fl-sidebar>

    <div #scrollContainer class="main-container" fxFlex>
      <router-outlet #o="outlet" (activate)="onActivate()"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>

Given the size of my project, what is the best and easiest way to ensure flex-layout works as expected in Angular 18?

First of all the experimental @angular/flex-layout package is deprecated since v15 https://blog.angular.dev/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127 so migrating to something else would be the best way to go for the future. In the meantime, though, are there any errors in the console?

Also what is the desired result? Because the screen doesn't seem big enough to fit everything. So at some point I would expect horizontal overflow.

The Angular team has ceased publishing new releases for this project. For more details, see Farewell, Flex Layout. If you have a large project and still need to use Flex Layout with the latest version of Angular, consider switching to @ngbracket/ngx-layout. To update your current project, simply modify the import as follows:
//remove all @angular/flex-layout    
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout'; // not supported

// replace it by @ngbracket/ngx-layout
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@ngbracket/ngx-layout';


This solution saved my day. Thanks for sharing.
